# Not receiving event for updated @Published

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to understand Combine a little bit and have an issue and can't wrap my head around it:

I got this data-source

```
class NoteManager: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  @Published var notes: [Note] = []
  var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
  init() {
    cancellable = $notes.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
      print("receiveCompletion \(completion)")
    }, receiveValue: { notes in
      print("receiveValue \(notes)")
    })
  }
}
```

which is used here:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var noteManager: NoteManager
    
      var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
          NavigationView {
            VStack {
              List {
                ForEach(noteManager.notes) { note in
                  NoteCell(note: note)
                }
              }
...
```

And I can change the values here:

```
    struct NoteCell: View {
      @State var note: Note
      
      var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TextField("title", text: $note.title)
...
```

Anyways - I'm not receiving the `receiveValue` event after changing the value (which is also correctly reflected in the ui). `receiveValue` is only called initially when setting it - is there some other way to receive an event for updated fields?

Add on:

```
struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {
  var id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var information:  String
}
```

Comment: @Asperi unless of course `Note` itself is an `ObservableObject` whose `title` is `@Published`

Comment: It would also help to use `@ObservedObject` instead of `@State` for both Note and NoteManager.

Comment: @Michael, would you show what is Note?

Comment: note is a struct - therefore @ObservedObject is not an option - Do I need to make it a class in order to detect changes?

Comment: I added the Note struct to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make manager observed object (as it is design pair for observable)

```
    struct ContentView: View {
      @ObservedObject var noteManager: NoteManager
```

2. make cell editing original note via binding (as note is struct)

```
    struct NoteCell: View {
      @Binding var note: Note
```

3. transfer note by projected value directly from manager (single source of truth) to cell (editor)

```
    ForEach(Array(noteManager.notes.enumerated()), id: \.element) { i, note in
      NoteCell(note: $noteManager.notes[i])
    }
```